# Ни одна пара не подходит под условие в моём коде для решения 17 задания ЕГЭ, не могу понять почему

Tags: python

В общем вот ссылка на задание - https://inf-ege.sdamgia.ru/problem?id=37368

Вот мой код:

```py
with open('17.txt') as f:
    s = [int(i) for i in f]
r = []
for i in range(len(s) - 1):
    for j in range(i + 1, len(s)):
        if (s[i] + s[j] % 60 == 0) and ((s[i] % 40 == 0) or (s[j] % 40 == 0)):
            r.append(s[i] + s[j])
print(len(r), max(r))
```

Как я понял, дело в том, что ни одна пара не подходит под условие, потому что `len(r)` остаётся равным нулю после выполнения кода. При этом список `s` заполняется правильно. Я разное попробовал, но просто нигде не вижу ошибки. PyCharm ошибок в коде не показывает

Comment: `s[n]` -> `s[i]`, `s[m]` -> `s[j]`

Comment: ой, начудил, не то написал, ща исправлю

Comment: оно всё равно не работает. Эта ошибка появилась из-за того, что я пытался хоть как-нибудь всё исправить и постепенно менял всё так же, как и на сайте с ответом

Comment: "не работает" не является описанием проблемы.

Comment: @user7860670 исправил

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скорее всего проблема в приоритете операторов

```
import dis


dis.dis("a + b % 60")
```

Вывод:

```
1             0 LOAD_NAME                0 (a)
              2 LOAD_NAME                1 (b)
              4 LOAD_CONST               0 (60)
              6 BINARY_MODULO
              8 BINARY_ADD
             10 RETURN_VALUE
```

Сначала идёт деление по модулю (`BINARY_MODULO`), затем сложение (`BINARY_ADD`), т. е. получается `s[i] + (s[j] % 60)`. Для решения можно просто добавить скобки:

```
(s[i] + s[j]) % 60
```